# How to rewrite this C# code that deals with a Stream and a byte buffer

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have this C# code:

```cs
const int bufferLen = 4096;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
int count = 0;
while ((count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
{
   outstream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

I need to rewrite it in F#. I can do it like this:

```
let bufferLen : int = 4096
let buffer : byte array = Array.zeroCreate bufferLen
let count : int = 0

let mutable count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)
if count > 0 then
   outstream.Write(buffer, 0, count)

while (count > 0) do
   count <- stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)
   outstream.Write(buffer, 0, count)
```

But may be there is a more functional way ?

Comment: Loops and mutable variables are usually replaced with recursion (and pattern matching) in functional languages.

Comment: I know, but I have a shared buffer and stream. Is it safe to pass them as parameters to a function ?

Comment: @demas I know it's side-stepping the problem at hand, but why not use [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Stream.CopyToAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158751%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? :)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek it's not side-stepping - it's the obvious thing to do ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from Patryk's point on comment:

It's a really imperative problem so it will not get much prettier.

The only thing I would try to change is the repeated read/writes - maybe like this:

```
let copyInto (outstream : System.IO.Stream) (stream : System.IO.Stream) =
    let bufferLen : int = 4096
    let buffer : byte array = Array.zeroCreate bufferLen

    let rec copy () =
        match stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen) with
        | count when count > 0 ->
            outstream.Write(buffer, 0, count)
            copy ()
        | _ -> ()

    copy ()
```